# Syntax Error on token "int", @ expected

Tags: syntax, token

I am writing a game project for University.
I created a simple class but keep getting this error at the line of "public int getP(){".
The error is this:
 *Syntax Error on token "int", @ expected.
 Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatment.
 Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName.*
I am going crazy right now..
Thanks for any help..

```
public class GameObjekt {
int Posx;
int Posy;
int AbsPosx;
int AbsPosy;
public GameObjekt(){
    Posx = 4;

    public int getP(){
        return Posx;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
public class GameObjekt {
    int Posx;
    int Posy;
    int AbsPosx;
    int AbsPosy;
    public GameObjekt(){
        Posx = 4;
    }

    public int getP(){
        return Posx;
    }
}
```

I guess you didn't close the constructor ?